# How to run the TcmReIndex tool?

Tags: search

We are trying to run the TcmReIndex.exe but the Administrator user is not allowed to run it. How can we find out who ran the Tridion installer or how can we find the user that has access to the encryption key?

When trying this (from the SDL doc below):

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "<domain>\<account>"
```

it generates an error.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKey
Container" "sys\admin"
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.18408
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container...
The RSA key container was not found.
Failed!
```

SDL's "Granting users access to encryption functionality"

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_215FCD336DE34DD5AD342951F6AB3683?

***** UPDATE *****

Ok, I succeeded executing `aspnet_regiis` and added my domain account. The acccount I'm using is the same account I used to install Tridion but still I get this error:

[image]

Where is the reindex tool user defined?

I found that the re-index tool works with `/config/Tridion.ContentManager.config` and there is a tag called `<Impersonationusers>` with the default user `NT_AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE`, I added my domain accoount and restarted Tridion Services to no avail.

Comment: That's an improvement. So now your account has access to the configuration, but is not a trustee in Tridion. If you add your user to Tridion and give yourself suitable permissions, that will help. It's probably best to make yourself a sysadmin if you are going to reindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally made the re-Index tool work. Like Dominic said the first step woill be to find the user in the Component Services snap-in. The second step is to create an user account in Tridion for that user with all rights. Adding the user to the Trustees table did not work for me nor adding that user to the Tridion_cm database in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to open the Component Services snap-in, and check the identity tab for the Tridion application (on my system this is called "SDL Web Content Manager") This identity is most likely the one used for the installation, but of course, it could have been changed since.

If that doesn't work, my next suggestion would be to try it for all the users who have logged in to the server. The easiest way to know this is to check which users have a folder in the Users folder on the system. (I'm not sure how accurate that is, but probably good enough.) For one of them, the aspnet_regiis command should succeed. With a bit of luck, that won't be too many. Good luck.

Once you track it down, I would also suggest exporting the key and making a safe backup. Check the [documentation for aspnet_regiis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) for how to do this

Comment: It is probably the first account added to the system. The MTSUser is not usually the one used to install the server. Check the user list for the lowest tcm ID (or look in the trustees table)

Comment: It's not that uncommon to use the mtsuser account. Happens oftener than you might think.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated the question. Still having issues running the TcmReIndex tool.